# Error CS1501: No overload for method 'AddArtist' takes 1 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this method in my ArtistDB class.

```
public string AddArtist(Artist ar)
```

and

```
ArtistDB obj = new ArtistDB();
        obj.AddArtist(ab);
```

It's giving this error while passing variable the `ab` to the `obj` instance of ArtistDB.

Error CS1501: No overload for method 'AddArtist' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Check if there are any other errors reported while compiling the ArtistDB class. If it has been compiled successfully, the method should be available.

Comment: Copy error message from title into question.

Comment: Try rebuilding the entire solution.